# Create View with two RecyclerViews for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I then have the following code:

```
public class UserStatusAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserStatusAdapter.UserResultsViewHolder> {

    Context mCtx;

    List<String> winnerPlayers;
    List<String> loserPlayers;

    public UserStatusAdapter(Context mCtx, List<String> winners, List<String> losers) {

        this.mCtx = mCtx;

        this.winnerPlayers = winners;
        this.loserPlayers = losers;

    }

    @Override
    public UserResultsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.userstatus_list_layout, parent,false);

        UserStatusAdapter.UserResultsViewHolder userResultsViewHolder = new UserStatusAdapter.UserResultsViewHolder(view);

        return userResultsViewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserStatusAdapter.UserResultsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final String winners = winnerPlayers.get(position);

        // ?? How do I account for the losers list ??

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return winnerPlayers.size() + loserPlayers.size();

    }

    static class UserResultsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public UserResultsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }

    }

}
```

How do I account for both recyclerviews in the onbindviewholder?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to display here? It looks like the logic is broken here.

In order for you to understand, you need to answer the following questions:
How do lists relate to each other? Are these two independent lists, or is one nested within the other?

If these lists are not related to each other, then you need two RecyclerViews, the adapter may be able to reuse or create your own for the second RecyclerView.

If one list is nested within another, you also need a second RecyclerView, the nested list must be treated in the same way as any other view.

The only difference is that the root element in the layout will be different for them, although the nested list case is a little more complicated.

Comment: My rationalization on having the two lists in one view is for players to navigate to and determine their status i the game. If they are still in then they are in the winners list, if not then in the loser list. The data is all housed in one table which holds their status of either winner or loser.

Comment: It’s very difficult, you don’t have to. What's stopping you from making two lists? The viewholder has only one position, you will not link and order these two lists in any way, if only because the number of winners and losers is not equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/recyclerView1" />

    <!-- Other views can be added here if needed -->

</RelativeLayout>





JAVA:

RecyclerView recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
RecyclerView recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);

RecyclerView.Adapter<YourDataModel1> adapter1 = new YourAdapter1(yourDataList1);
recyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

RecyclerView.Adapter<YourDataModel2> adapter2 = new YourAdapter2(yourDataList2);
recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```